# How can I add a shift register to Ben Eater's 65(C)02 computer?

Tags: shift-register

I made [Ben Eater's 65C02 computer](https://eater.net/6502) recently, and I wanted to know how to add a shift register to it for handling multiple inputs without taking up too much of the 65C22's pins. The shift register I have is [SN74HC595](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN74HC595.pdf). The first question I probably should ask is if it's compatible.

If it's compatible, could someone explain what I would need to do to put the 65C22 in shift register mode? From the datasheet, I gathered that I would need to connect the shift register to CB2, and the signal would come out at CB1. Where would I connect the other side of CB1? And how can I get the 65C02 to process the data?

If the answer is directly under my nose and I don't see it, please forgive me. I'm pretty new to this stuff and the datasheets all look like mumbo jumbo :)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "add a shift register"? Add it to do what?

Comment: sorry about that, is this better?

Comment: @MarstheLimit Do you mean you wish to now construct the Western Digital [W65C22N/S](https://eater.net/datasheets/w65c22.pdf)? Or use one you already have?

Comment: @periblepsis, that is what I’m going for

Comment: The 595 is a serial-in-parallel-out device. If you want parallel inputs, then this is not the chip you are looking for.

Comment: @Justme, serial inputs would actually be what I'm going for. I want to make something that loosely resembles the NES, and I found out that this is what the NES controllers do.

Comment: Yes but what does that have to with 65C22 then? It's already a shift register you can clock bits in serially and have the CPU access the whole byte in parallel?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Can you explain this to me?